# Send custom row of listview to another listview in another activity

Tags: android, listview, variables, tabs, adapter

I want to send specific rows of listview inside, for example, tab1 and send them to the final tab that is tab6.

So the listview in tab6 is update automatically as i pick rows from other listview.

Now i show you how it looks like my activity: (see the image)

[image]

When i switch between tabs i lose variables change inside viewpager

Suppose we have to send "Cosmopolitan" to "Bevande"(Tab). I add quantity with imagebutton to 2 for example, so when i send it to "Bevande"(Tab) i can see the name and the quantity.

Is it possible to do it?

For any code ask me

Comment: what you can do is when there is any change in quantity, add your custom object in a list & pass it onto the next fragment and when that particular fragment is selected inflate your view & get the data from the passed List.

Comment: How to do that in my case? i can put the code you want